# Rails: Responding to XML

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking to respond to XML.  In my show action, I have something like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {
    render :action => 'show'
  }
  format.xml {
    render :xml => @post.to_xml
  }
end
```

This will output all of the post's attributes.  How would you go about outputting only some of the post's attributes.  Also, say that Post belongs_to User.  How would you then take this one step further by outputting the user's name with the post's XML (rather than the foreign key given to the post)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@post.to_xml(:except => [:foo, :bar], :include => :user)
```

The docs on to_xml go into more detail

Comment: This works well.  However, if i use something like @post.to_xml(:only => [:created_at, :updated_at], :include => :user), the created_at and updated_at columns are displayed for both the post and the user.  Is it possible to only specify the :created_at and :updated_at columns for the post - e.g. 'post.created_at'?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: the documentation describes how to get access to the xml builder object for advanced uses.  the :include option can also take a hash which specifies options that will go to the included items e.g. :include => {:user => {:only => :foo}}

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that you can pass :only and :except options to the :include:

```
@post.to_xml(:only => [:created_at, :updated_at], :include => {:user => {:only => :name}})
```

This will get the created_at and updated_at columns for the post and the name for the associated user.